# How to detect network type(2G/3G) in J2ME?

Tags: networking, java-me

In my J2ME application i want to detect network type whether it is 2G or 3G. According to network type, i need to take some different actions. How can it be done by code?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For Network type following syntax is used

```
String value = System.getProperty("com.nokia.network.access");
```

You can check this [artical](http://library.developer.nokia.com/index.jsp?topic=/Java_Developers_Library/GUID-A1F90B63-5F14-4829-BCA1-A23B925CF670.html).

The return values can be as follows,

- **pd** - Packet data in GSM network
- **pd.EDGE** - Packet data in EDGE network
- **pd.3G** - Packet data in 3G network
- **pd.HSDPA** - High speed downlink packet access for 3G networks
- **csd** - Circuit switched data, for example GSM CSD/HSCSD data call
- **bt_pan** - Bluetooth PAN network
- **wlan** - Wireless network, for example 802.11b, 802.11G or WiMaX
- **na** - Not applicable, the implementation can’t determine the type

So based on return value, you can get the Network Type.

Comment: hey i have tried in my LG phone like System.getProperty("com.lge.imei") .but its giving me null.why its like this?

Comment: so can you give me correct syntax? beacuse i have taken this syntax from internet only. see i m giving you link also [link](http://ashnatechnologies.blogspot.in/2010/01/how-to-get-device-imei-number-using.html)

Comment: Actually, isn't com.nokia.network.access Nokia specific? I think for  other manufacturers you have to consult their SDK documentation / developer page, that should be your starting point. Simply substituting com.nokia with other name is most likely wrong.